# Does AskUbuntu have a say in what side adds are put up?

Tags: discussion, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some SE network ads are offtopic/inappropriate.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1461/some-se-network-ads-are-offtopic-inappropriate)

I recently saw a side add that was a bit surprising, albeit quite funny...

[image]

Maybe we could limit the ads to a limited scope of relevant stack exchange sites?

Does Ask Ubuntu screen these? Or are we at the mercies of other stackexchanges on this.

Comment: Other Stack Exchange sites don't pick which questions show up in the sidebar, they're chosen based on the most popular question in a given timespan then auto-generated.

Comment: so, we will always see very inappropriate questions, because they are most popular. I'm going to ad-block.

Comment: Since that question was asked, content filtering has been put in place to avoid questions like the one asked in the original meta post. However, you'll still see a small amount of ads that may or may not be relevant to you from other SE networks in addition to our own [Community Ads](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2158/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)